# Understanding different Docker components

Tags: linux, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I've very simple theoretical questions. We used Docker in VirtualBox before **Docker Desktop for Windows** and Mac OS launched officially. In Virtual Box, we get a VM and we manage it using `docker-machine` command whereas we usually don't use `docker-machine` if we use Docker Desktop for Windows and Mac OS. Now keeping in the view of both versions:

1. What is Docker Host and What it does in Both Versions?
2. Docker Client is now referred as any terminal on Windows if we use Docker for Windows? (Do we now not need to configure our terminal as Docker Client to manage our containers?)
3. Are the Docker Engine and Docker Daemon the same or different things in both versions?
4. What is the role of MobyLinux VM in Hyper-V in Windows?
5. How Docker isolates our application from the Host OS?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker host is where your containers run. As docker containers need to run under linux, if you're on a mac or windows you can only run them locally on your machine if you have a linux vm running.

1. On VirtualBox, the docker host is an instance of boot2docker, which is a very lightweight linux. On docker4mac, the host is effectively your mac (each container actually runs under a "micro linux" called xhyve, but that's for the details)
2. A docker client is simply any terminal that runs the Docker Client application, which is a CLI application that communicates with a Docker Daemon running inside the host.
3. As far as I understand, the Docker engine and docker daemon are the same even in Docker 4 mac/windows.
4. I don't know about MobyLinux
5. Container isolation from the host (and other containers) is achieved using namespace, cgroup and private networks. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/ I however don't believe that security like cgroup are enabled by default.

All good questions...

Comment: Thanks for answer, The last thing is don't you think that MobyLinux is where Docker Host runs and initiate it? As it was in VirtualBox before?

Comment: I just had a quick look at MobyLinux. Yes, it's the linux image used in docker4windows. It's the equivalent of boot2docker when using VirtualBox except that it seems to have very good integration with Windows (shared drives).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to Docker Daemon, Docker Engine, Docker client, Docker host, and how Docker works, please refer to [Understanding Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/) and [Docker Engine page](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-engine). There have clearly architecture structure and explanation.

For question 4, Docker should runs in Linux, so Docker for Windows will create a Linux "MobyLinux" VM to run Docker components.

Comment: A port of the Docker open source (ie, architecturally referred to as daemon or engine) to Windows is soon to be released by Micrsoft for Windows Server 2016, and is also available from WinDocks for Windows 8, Windows !0, Server 2012 and Server 2016.

Comment: What's the relation between boot2docker and MobyLinux?

Comment: @Kitanotori I can't find enough info between these two components. But to me, boot2docker more like a toolbox designed for Mac and Windows user. And boot2docker contains a tiny linux distribution called boot2docker linux, which should similar with MobyLinux.